# Google Chrome Print event capture after selecting Print from menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have successfully captured the Ctrl+P event using the following jQuery, but the same code is not executed when you select "Print" from the menu, or by right clicking the page and selecting "Print".  Both of these menu's show the shortcut "Ctrl+P" as a hint next to them, but apparently Chrome is not actually triggering the keys.

```
    $(document).bind("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
            printReport("#jsGrid");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Is there a way to capture the other print events?

Using Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to intercept a user printing from the Chrome menu, at least not from a webpage. You might be able to accomplish this with a chrome extension using the [`onPrintRequested`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/printerProvider#event-onPrintRequested) method. If you are trying to prevent users from printing your page contents, you might try using CSS:

```
@media print {
   body { display: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: Ok.  We were trying to avoid having extra "printable" data on the page, only to be displayed by CSS when print is triggered.  Reason being that a very small percentage of page visits will result in printing, and it's a lot of data in some instances.